# Joomla CMS ajax request format=row not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla3.0

I'm doing a custom Joomla component using newest version 3.3 . in my edit.php I'm trying to send an ajax request via jQuery.ajax.
Strange thing is code in my previous project doesn't work anymore. Previous project done with joomla 3.0 .
Here is my ajax request.

```
jQuery("#getUser").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

       var user_id= jQuery("#jform_user_id").val();
       var data = 'user_id='+user_id;
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=myviewlist&task=reservation.getUserDetails",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
           alert(data);
        }
    });
```

I accidentally put add "format" in to url and it works fine.

```
jQuery("#getUser").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

       var user_id= jQuery("#jform_user_id").val();
       var data = 'user_id='+user_id;
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=myviewlist&task=reservation.getUserDetails&format",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
           alert(data);
        }
    });
```

notice the "format" in url. If I put format=row it not works. Can anyone give me a hint, whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: You might get a better response on the Joomla Stack Exchange website at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you mean to use URL param format=raw?  If so,  does the view in question have a supporting view.raw.php file?

Comment: There is no supporting view.raw.php .
In all my previous projects 2.5x and 3x I didn't used view.raw.php.
instead I used above code with format=raw. But it doesn't work anymore with joomla 3.3

Comment: I'll check jooma stack exchange @NeilRobertson  . Thanks for the information.